# Why did I only get status code 1 and not a Python error message when I supplied the wrong value to EMAIL_BACKEND?

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

I wanted to send an email with Django(`1.5`), in my console it looked like the following:

```
In [30]: send_mail("bla", "here it is", "from_address@gmail.com", 
["to_address@gmail.com"], fail_silently=False)

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: bla
From: from_address@gmail.com
To: to_address@gmail.com
Date: Sat, 14 Dec 2013 11:56:37 -0000
Message-ID: <20131214115637.4720.60719@my_username-E531>

here it is
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Out[30]: 1
```

Eventually I found the problem was caused because `EMAIL_BACKEND` (containing `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`)  in `settings.common.py` was being overwritten by `EMAIL_BACKEND` (containing `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`) in `settings.dev.py` with a different value.

The only explicit clue I had that something went wrong was `Out[30]: 1`, as I understand an  exit status of an unsuccessful run of a process.

1. How come I didn't get any Python error?
2. Was there a way to get the Python error for this error? If this was not possible how should I have debugged this properly?

Comment: Check, and now your interactive session output makes much more sense too! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value you see is the number of messages processed. From the [`django.core.mail.backends.base.BaseEmailBackend.send_messages()` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/base.py#L35):

> ```
> def send_messages(self, email_messages):
>     """
>     Sends one or more EmailMessage objects and returns the number of email
>     messages sent.
>     """
> ```

The backend you are using, even though it is the wrong one, is indicating it sent 1 message.

If this is the `django.core.mail.console.EmailBackend()` backend, that just means 1 message was written to `sys.stdout`, but otherwise not forwarded to a SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! I found it really strange that an exit status would have been used to indicate this behavior. I guess that could've been possible if the person who programmed the involved part would just use `sys.stderr.write` instead of raising a Python error. I'm glad I was wrong! : )

Comment: No, I'm wrong. `sys.stderr.write` would look different, it would not be outputted behind the `Out` Ipython prompt. You'd have to use print for that.

Comment: @Bentley4: `console.EmalBackend()` writes to `sys.stdout`, just as `print` would.

Comment: @Bentley4: But writing to `sys.stderr` would look just the same here. The write takes place *before* the call returns.

Comment: My false assumptions again. I only checked `sys.stdout.write`, `sys.stderr.write` and not `print`... . Forgot that only return statements (afaik) have that `Out` prompt in `Ipython`. I should have known and checked before writing that down. Sorry!